# Does editing an old post bring it up to the front?

Tags: discussion, edits, bump, last-activity

Does editing an old post bring it up to the top of the queue like a new post?

If this is the case, can people just edit their old posts that have not been answered instead of offering a bounty on them?

Comment: Did you ***really*** just edit this post to add "Thanks"? I mean, [I know that's what happened, I see the evidence right in front of my face](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/290345/revisions), but I cannot believe it. Hope you enjoy that hat. Don't do this again.

Answer (score 18):

Editing a post counts as "activity".  If someone is sorting on activity, they'll see recently edited posts.  If they're not, then they won't.

If you see someone making lots of meaningless edits just to cause activity for a post, flag for moderator attention and they can deal with such abuse.

Comment: it would not be good to flag the post, as its just a rouge user making all the new activity?

Comment: @MZaragoza You should flag any post that is being constantly edited with meaningless edits, regardless of who's making them.

Comment: does activity count with deleted posts to?

Comment: @Servy If the post is edited by a third party (one other than origin writer), is it cause to bring the post to the top of the list?

Comment: One way to prove that someone is making trivial edits to bump up the post, is to check the edit history and the intervals between edits.