# What to do after having edited a bad question of yours?

Tags: support, edits, bump

What do you have to do after one of your questions has been downvoted, and you edited it? The question obviously won't get any more attention (Unless it isn't edited within the first minutes after posting), so is there a way to make the downvoters reconsider their decision?

[Does editing a old post bring it up to the front?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290345/does-editing-a-old-post-bring-it-up-to-the-front) only answers a part of my question, and only if you know about Servy's accepted answer below (Which, by the way, is more complete anyway.)

(Quite a few of my questions have been downvoted, and I mostly don't know what I could improve, so of course my future questions won't get better either... Anyhow, apparently this has been discussed enough times on here, so I won't start the discussion about that again.)

Comment: On the contrary:  edited questions show up on the front page for a time.

Comment: @Makoto Oh, okay. I guess I didn't edit my question well enough then.

Comment: @Makoto Not strictly true on SO.  Each question has a "score" that is computed using a number of factors, including use of tags marked as interesting for the current user, net score of votes, the score of answers to it, and indeed time since last activity.  Editing the post will improve that score by resetting the "last activity" *portion*, but that may not increase the post by enough for it to make it onto for most people, although it could for some.  On sites other than SO it's just a list of questions sorted by activity, and so editing a question will put it on the homepage.

Comment: Related: [Feature Request - Notification on edit of downvoted content](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/notification-on-edit-of-downvoted-content)

Comment: @Servy:  Funnily enough, whenever I've edited older questions they've shown up on the front page.   Maybe it's just me.

Comment: @Makoto It may very well be just you.  As I discussed, the homepage is personalized for each person.  it's also going to depend on what the "score" is for each other category, and how far off the question was from being on the homepage before you edited it.  Editing certainly *can* put the question on your homepage, or move it onto the homepage for another user that didn't have it before, but it won't *necessarily* do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does editing a old post bring it up to the front?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290345/does-editing-a-old-post-bring-it-up-to-the-front)

Comment: @gnat Honestly, this should be discussed in an, uh, discussion. This is not the first time that one of my posts gets marked as a duplicate, whereas I don't think it is: Because the question itself is different, even if the answer can be found (indirectly) in the linked post. For this concrete example: My question rather was if I could somehow notify the  downvoters and tell them that I edited the question, but of course the answer on the linked post kind of answers this question too. But only because of Servy's answer and the comments here.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Comment: FWIW bump and fresh views of _other_ users is the right thing to do here. I love it how everyone thinks those who voted down/close will change their mind after edit. They're biased and they are less likely to change. I for one often come upon bumped posts I voted down/close - and _very_ infrequently revert my vote (though, when I _have to revert_, it usually feels... great)

Comment: @gnat So I should edit my question right now and write something like "*your link* only answers a part of my question, and only when knowing about Servys answer on this post"?

Comment: @gnat I edited it now, is it good or bad?

Comment: much better; in fact, the edit made me think that duplicate close in _opposite_ direction would make sense now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users sorting questions based on activity, rather than when the question was asked, will be seeing recently edited content as well as new content, and so are much more likely to notice such posts.

There is (by design) no way to directly draw attention to those that have voted on a post.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So either I manage to edit my question reaaally good and I get lucky enough to get it noticed, or I can basically forget about posting here?

Comment: @Fly While questions do get *more* attention when they're new, and may get additional attention when edited, plenty of questions get answers from someone that just happens upon the question a long time later, even without being drawn to it form recent activity.  You certainly can't give up on any shot of it being answered; it's just *less likely*.  Of course, if you really want to draw attention to your question, use a bounty.  It's why they exist.

Comment: @Fly If you want to get good at asking questions, you may want to read and absorb this:   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   Generally including code examples in brief fashion, with an explanation of what you tried, what works and what doesn't goes over well.  :)